# Spring Data Cassandra Connection Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to connect Spring data cassandra I have cassandra server running on  network. Here are the details

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=192.168.33.10
spring.data.cassandra.cluster-name=GEO-LOCAL-Cluster
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=organizationlicenses
spring.data.cassandra.username=cassandra
spring.data.cassandra.password=cassandra
```

I have prefixed them through spring.data as I was trying to auto inject these properties. But, most examples and information i came across are using configuration class extended as below 
CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration ...

```
@Bean
public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster = 
      new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(properties.getContactPoints());
    cluster.setPort(properties.getPort());
    cluster.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
    cluster.setPassword(properties.getPassword());

    return cluster;
}
```

Here is the exception i get -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/DemoClientCassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.33.10:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
```

I am not sure what I am missing. How do I specify the clustername GEO-LOCAL-Cluster using configuration class. I have traced all the properties are populated correctly.

I have used @Table on entity class and @EnableCassandraRepositories on the main method of application.

Comment: Whats is session bean??

Answer (score 1):

Following are the three mandatory settings to setup the connection for a Cassandra client:

- Setup the host name(contactPoints) on which Cassandra server is running
- Port is simply the listening port.
- KeyspaceName is the namespace that defines the data replication on
  nodes,  based on a Cassandra related concept.

**Configuration for the Cassandra**

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    //Must override this method
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "sampleKeySpace";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = 
          new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9142);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() 
      throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }
}
```

**Create the EntityCassandraRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CassandraRepository<Entity> {

}
```

**Configuration for the same repo**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
  basePackages = "org.yates.data.cassandra.repository")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

}
```